# Scroll Event in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a question, how to handle the scroll event when I scroll my mouse to adjust volume of a `MediaElement`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the [UIElement.MouseWheel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.mousewheel.aspx) event.

I'd offer more, but I don't know how your app is structured.  If you are using MVVM, etc.